# Is this sequence theorem true?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> If a sequence $\{a_n\}$ of non-negative reals is convergent, then $\{\sqrt a_n \}$ is also convergent.

Is this proposition true?

I think it is true but I don't know why it does make sense.

If it is false, tell me under what condition it is true.

Comment: If everything makes sense, then it is true.

Comment: What if $a_n=-\frac1n$?

Comment: are you sure you don't mean $L>0$?

Comment: i just have edited that condition.

Comment: @cokecokecoke: even $L >0$ won't work always. you can have some $a_n <0.$ you need all $a_n \geq 0.$

Comment: @Krish If the sequence converges to $L > 0$, then $a_n > 0$ for all sufficiently large $n$, which is close enough.

Comment: @fkraiem: that's true. but my point was to emphasis that to talk about $\sqrt{a}$ (in $\mathbb{R}$) one needs $a \geq 0.$ that was the whole point of all the comments above. I didn't want to discard finitely many terms, though it won't make any difference in convergence.

Comment: If it's not true, it's not a theorem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break it down to definitions.  For $\{a_n\}$ to converge to $L$,  it means that for any $\epsilon >0,\exists N\in \mathbb N$ such that $\forall n \ge n,|a_n -L|<\epsilon $

Now,  you want to show that $\{\sqrt {a_n}\}$ converges, so first you need to know where it converges to,  the obvious (and correct) answer is $\sqrt L$.  So, to prove that, you start with an arbitrary $\epsilon >0$.  Now, we want to find a $N \in \mathbb N$  such that for any number $n\ge N$,   $|\sqrt {a_n} -\sqrt L|<\epsilon $.

From here, can you find the $N$ that will work?  Hint:  you can use ANY number greater than $0$ from the first sequence converging, so you can use numbers of the form $2\cdot \epsilon,\epsilon ^2,\sqrt \epsilon $, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it’s true.

Two ways of looking at it:

- $\sqrt{·}$ as a function $[0..∞) → [0..∞)$ is continuous, so if $a_n \overset{n → ∞}→ a$ then $\sqrt{a_n} \overset{n → ∞}→ \sqrt{a}$ (this is the convergent sequence criterion for continuity).
- More elementary: Assume the limit $a = \lim_{n → ∞} a_n$ is not zero. Let $ε > 0$. Then choose $δ = \sqrt{a}ε$, so if $|a_n - a| < δ$, you get
  $$|\sqrt{a_n} - \sqrt{a}| = \frac{|a_n - a|}{|\sqrt{a_n} + \sqrt{a}|} < \frac{δ}{\sqrt a} = ε,$$
  and you can proceed to show convergence by definition, using the definition of the convergence of $(a_n)$ (that’s what the $δ$ is for). And for the case $a = 0$ you may choose $δ = ε^2$ and proceed similarly.

Note that by this you essentially prove the continuity of $\sqrt{·}$ using the sequence criterion.

Comment: For the elementary part,  pretty sure you want the $N$ formulation, not the $\delta$ formulation, since we're talking about sequences, not functions.  (See my 'hinted' version)

Comment: @Alan Yeah, I updated my version: With the given argument you can run through the definition of the convergence of $(\sqrt{a_n})_n$ and lead it back to the convergence of $(a_n)_n$.

Comment: The elementary part wouldn't work if the limit is $0$.

Comment: @egreg I know, I put “assume the limit is nonzero” there. The case where $(a_n)_n$ is a null sequence is of course more elementary in that $|\sqrt{a_n}|<ε ⇔ |a_n| < ε^2$, so choosing $δ=ε^2$ suffices – this is (arguably) less interesting and easier to prove, so I ommited it; but I included it now.

Answer (score 2):

Since we are doing *real* analysis, the sequence $\{\sqrt{a_n}\}$ may not even be defined. What if $\{a_n\}$ is the constant sequence with value $-1$?

However, as Git Gud said in his comment, if $\{\sqrt{a_n}\}$ actually exists (*i.e.*, if $a_n \ge 0$ for all $n$—or at least for all sufficiently large $n$ if you're willing to cheat a little), then it is true.

Comment: I have just edited that condition. It was my mistake.

Comment: @cokecokecoke The condition $L\ge0$ does not imply $a_n\ge0$.

Comment: how can we prove it?

Comment: Applying the standard definition of a limit would work without any particular difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

$$a_{n}>0\\|a_{n}-l|<\epsilon\\|\sqrt{a_{n}}-\sqrt{l}|<\epsilon'\\|\sqrt{a_{n}}-\sqrt{l}|<\epsilon'\frac{|\sqrt{a_{n}}+\sqrt{l}|}{|\sqrt{a_{n}}+\sqrt{l}|}\\|a_{n}-l|<\epsilon'|\sqrt{a_{n}}+\sqrt{l}|<\epsilon'(|\sqrt{a_{n}}|+|\sqrt{l}|)<\epsilon'2max{|\sqrt{a_{n}}|}\\$$if name maximum a(n) az M so we have 
$$ \epsilon'2max{|\sqrt{a_{n}}|}<\\|a_{n}-l|<\epsilon<\epsilon'2M\\\epsilon'=\frac{\epsilon}{2M+1}$$